# DEB: multi-package, ignore installation of some files during packages building

Tags: deb

I've overridden `dh_auto_install:` target in `debian/rule` file. Now, all my built components installed in `debian/tmp`.

I prepared `package.install` for every package of my set but I have this issue:

Package `A` should contains `scripts` with two files.

Package `B` should contains `scripts` dir too but without two files that will be in package `A`.

Of cause it's possible to set files in `scripts` dir in `debian/B.install` file. But `scripts` dir contains huge count of files and put every of it will take a more time.

Is it possible to exclude some particular files in `package.install` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to exclude some particular files in `package.install` file?

Not directly, but there are at least three ways of achieving what you’re after. (Since you mention overriding `dh_install`, I’m guessing you’re using short-`dh` style `rules`.)

1. `dh_install` *copies* files from `debian/tmp` to their target. Its predecessor, `dh_movefiles`, moves them; it’s deprecated but can still be used in this kind of situation. The way to do this is to list package `A` before package `B` in `debian/control` (so it’s processed first, assuming both have the same architecture), rename `A.install` to `A.files`, and override `dh_install` so that it runs `dh_movefiles` first:

   ```
   override_dh_install:
           dh_movefiles
           dh_install
   ```

   This will move the files for `A` out of `debian/tmp`, so your `B.install` file can then list `scripts` and `B` will have all the files that are left in `scripts`.

   The `dh` sequences skip `dh_movefiles` so there’s nothing special to do to avoid its running twice.
2. `debhelper` configuration files can be executable, so you could replace `B.install` with a script which lists `scripts`’ contents and filters out anything that’s in `A.install`.
3. Another approach would be to add a step after `dh_install` which removes anything in `A` from `B`; something like

   ```
   override_dh_install:
           dh_install
           cd debian/A/scripts; find . -type f -exec rm -f ../B/scripts/{} \;
   ```

   (untested).

Comment: Many thank's! Great answer as always! I didn't know that `debhelper` configuration files may be executable. Possibly I omit this fact when was reading "Debian New Maintainers' Guide". Strange that this feature isn't  exists in any of `debhelper` utility. RPM spec files instead has `%exclude` macro  for `%files` section to achieve this target.